# Postman - Store intercepted requests in history

Tags: web-services, google-chrome-extension, postman, execute

In previous versions of postman, it was possible to store the history of intercepted webservices using the :
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47lOy.png)
I have the impression that this is no longer possible. Is there a solution?
Perhaps a way of reverting to the old interface?
Thank you,
Théo